# Global Function in Socket.io Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Greetings all socket IO experts, 
I have a scenario i have written a global function to send private messages.
Whenever a user sends private message, inside the global function i retrieve socket.username value but it always returns wrong value probably last logged in user's socket.username value.

When i change the function to normal javascript function (non global) it returns correct socket.username value.

Can anybody advise on this how do i achieve this inside the global function. As i have multiple JS exported code need to access global functions from other required code.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide a code?

Comment: global.privatechat=function(){ return socket.username;}